# Big Data Batch and Stream Data pipeline with Hadoop Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am designing this below flow and want to know if am going in the right way. i want to skip any unwanted steps if added. I have Hadoop running on spark engine.

- below pipeline has to pull the data in batch as well as streaming data.
- flow needs to pull the data and store in HDFS
- hive with mysql for metedata storage to run hive queries
- then need to perform complex ETL operations using pyspark
- then load the transformed data in rdbms
- data from rdbms will be reported using Apache Superset
- the complete flow should be run by a scheduler, for that using airflow
  can you please check and suggest if am missing something in order to make this flow robust

[image]

Comment: Seems fine. Please clarify what problems you are running into

Answer (score 1):

Use Debezium to pull from RDBMS. All writes therefore end up in Kafka, and you don't end up with "batches" at all. (Sqoop is a retired Apache project)

Use Apache Pinot or Druid to ingest Kafka directly. Then you don't need HDFS.

You can query Pinot / Druid using SQL. Or you can use Presto in place of Hive/SparkSQL, and you should be able to link SuperSet to Presto rather than an intermediate RDMBS.